# Bad Request at getObjectMetadata using AmazonS3Client

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bad-request

I have web application using spring-boot that trying to get metadata of object in AWS S3 running in tomcat server. My bucket region is `ap-southeast-1`. When I deployed my app in Elastic Beanstalk, it work well. But, after running without any request in couple of hours (usually at night) , I got `AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request`. And after restart tomcat, my app will works again.

Here's what i put in my application.properties file

```
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=[my-access-key]
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=[my-secret-key]
cloud.aws.region.static=ap-southeast-1
bucket.name=[my-bucket-name]
```

And this is how I call getObjectMetadata

```java
public static ObjectMetadata getMeta(final String fileName) throws IOException {
    String key = prefix + "/" + fileName;
    ObjectMetadata meta = s3client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, key);
    return meta;
}
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

UPDATE :

Here's how I setup my credentials :

```java
private static AWSCredentialsProvider provider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
private static AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(provider.getCredentials());
```

Comment: Is it possible that your app is using EC2 instance profile credentials and not the credentials in application.properties? The credentials expire and you get Bad Request (or do you get AccessDenied ... just double checking). Can you try printing the access key id and secret access key on your ec2 instance just to be sure?

Comment: I didn't set access key and secret key in ec2 instance environment (already checked that..). And i always get bad request. Do you have any other idea? @RohitBanga

Comment: How does your application use the access key id and secret access key from application.properties?

Comment: @RohitBanga i update my question, did I do something wrong?